# Use and costs of Creative Commons licenses in scholarly publishing

Tags: publications, reference-request, open-access, creative-commons

How often is which Creative Commons license used in scholarly publishing and are there differences between their use in gold (fully) open acces (OA) and hybrid articles?

I am looking for a table like this, with the amount of articles:

```
license       gold OA    hybrid OA
CC-BY         A          B
CC-BY-NC-ND   C          D
...
```

Additionally, what are the average charges for both types of articles (gold open access and hybrid) depending on the different licenses?

I am looking for a table like this, with the average costs of the license:

```
license      gold OA    hybrid OA
CC-BY        A          B
CC-BY-NC-ND  C          D
...
```

**Update:** Some results of my further research:

1. As mentioned in a comment, there is a [study](http://dx.doi.org/10.7328/jurpcb20153011) for gold open access journals. Hybrid journals are not investigated.
2. There is data availible from [OASPA members](http://oaspa.org/oaspa-members-ccby-growth-2015-data/). They provide a chart showing the growth of Fully Open Access (OA) journals using a CC-BY license. Additionally, there is an Excel file including also data for hybrid open access journals. Unfortunately, there is no information about the charges and the source of this data.

Comment: I am aware of [this study](http://dx.doi.org/10.7328/jurpcb20153011) but it only focuses on gold open access articles.

Comment: arXiv links article licenses in a well-defined place; you may want to farm their data. (My guess is most articles use the default, but well.)

Comment: Good point, @Raphael. Actually, I'm more focused on publisher data, not on pre-prints. But this would be interesting, too.

Comment: That would be more easy, I guess: there are probably very few publishers using CC licenses. The ratio of articles published thus is probably zero up to several decimal places. Therefore, I think you'll have to look outside of traditional publishing. Then the landscape is more diffuse: you have preprint servers, different databases for different disciplines (that have non-empty intersections), articles published only on their authors' websites, ...

Comment: No, it wouldn't. The number of publishers offering hybrid open access is no longer small and even just to find out which articles of only one subscription based journal are open access (hybrid) is not straight foreward.

Comment: I was not aware that "open access" at traditional publishers entailed a CC license. All models I have seen mean they keep their usual copyright -- everything that changes is that they make the article available for free (as in $0). This typically costs the authors a four-digit amount of dollars. If that has changed, I'm glad! (I doubt it, though. Giving something away for free does not challenge your business model in the way CC does.)

Comment: Hybrid articles are more and more published under CC licenses. You're right that this has been different in the past. I recently found a journal charging more for CC-BY than for CC-BY-NC-ND. That's when I started asking myself this question: Which license do most authors choose and what are the average charges by license?

Comment: I see; good things are happening then! Good luck in your quest, I'm afraid I can't be of help.

Comment: There is no CC-BY-N license. Did you mean NC? ND?

Comment: The three dots shall indicate that I'm interested in all CC licenses. Nevertheless, I corrected the question to a correct one. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: The "costs" of a bad license choice (e.g. using -NC when you have no plans to sell the work) are often hard to measure. Cf. https://www.ub.uit.no/wiki/noap/index.php/User:Nemo_bis/Elements_of_journal_freedom

Comment: @Nemo Your link leads to an empty page.

Comment: @FuzzyLeapfrog uh indeed, since a week ago. Archived here: https://web.archive.org/web/20171123080853/https://www.ub.uit.no/wiki/noap/index.php/User:Nemo_bis/Elements_of_journal_freedom

Comment: @Nemo Thank you so much! There is a very well written text explaining in detail why NC is not what most people think it is and why it shouldn't be used. Unfortunately, it's only available in German. https://irights.info/wp-content/uploads/userfiles/CC-NC_Leitfaden_web.pdf

Comment: @FuzzyLeapfrog yes, that's a leaflet we at Wikimedia helped make, it's translated at this page (linked from the page above): https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Free_knowledge_based_on_Creative_Commons_licenses

Answer (score 1):

Even though there is still no complete data set answering my question, I recently found a public data set at least answering my questions for hybrid OA. It's called [Hybrid Open Access Monitor](https://najkoja.shinyapps.io/hybridoa/). The [data](https://github.com/subugoe/hybrid_oa_dashboard/tree/master/data) and the [source code](https://github.com/subugoe/hybrid_oa_dashboard) is available on GitHub. It is based on data from Crossref and the [Open-APC dataset](https://treemaps.intact-project.org/), also [freely available](https://github.com/openapc/openapc-de) on GitHub. Some more explanation can be found on the [About](https://subugoe.github.io/hybrid_oa_dashboard/about.html) page. As an example, here are the numbers of hybrid articles published by Elsevier split into the different licences.

[image: This work is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International License. Author: Najko Jahn (Scholarly Communication Analyst, SUB Göttingen), 2017.]

This figure is licensed under a [Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International License](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/). Author: Najko Jahn (Scholarly Communication Analyst, SUB Göttingen), 2017.

You can also see, how much each country spent (relatively) of the total costs, if you go to the monitor's website.

For Gold Open Access, there is the [study](http://dx.doi.org/10.7328/jurpcb20153011) already mentioned in the question showing the usage of different CC licences.

Combining both will lead to a data set of the usage of CC licences in Gold and Hybrid Open Access. Nevertheless, regarding the costs, one has to dig even a bit deeper but I'm sure there will be published data soon and I will update this answer accordingly.